# htaccess, redirect and remove ID to new domain

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I changed my old domain to a new one.
The problem is, not only the domain will be replaced, but also all the url of each article.

For an example;

http://OLDdomain.com/read/100/this-is-url/
to,
http://NEWdomain.com/this-is-url/

I've tried several ways on .htaccess but not working
Thanks for help.

update

I've tried this formula in the old domain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDdomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.OLDdomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://NEWdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

this will return,
**NEWdomain.com/read/100/this-is-url/**
Not as I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your new domain is pointing to a diffrent document root, you can use the following redirect :

```
RedirectMatch ^/read/[0-9]+/(.+)$ http://newdomain.com/$1
```

Comment: where should i put this, in the old domain or new?

Comment: in your olddomain/.htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDdomain.com/read/([0-9]+)/(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.OLDdomain.com/read/([0-9]+)/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://NEWdomain.com/$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDdomain.com/(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.OLDdomain.com/(.*)
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://NEWdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: 100 is just an example ID from thousands of other IDs. It could be 101, 102 and so on

Comment: Simple is, I want to change `http://OLDdomain.com/read/{id}/{pretty url}/` to `http://NEWdomain.com/{pretty url}/`